# How to aggregate delegates into a new delegate with linq

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, aggregate

Let's say I have a `IEnumerable<Func<object, bool>>`. I want to make a new `Func<object, bool>` which should return true if every function of that list returns true when called on some object. In other words I want to aggregate (reduce\foldl) a list of functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Func<object, bool> aggregate = o => functions.All(f => f(o));
```

Of course this is cheating a little because the functions happen to return `bool` so we can use `Enumerable.All` directly to produce an aggregate result. Tthis also has the side effect that not all functions in the list will be called -- as soon as one returns `false` we pack up and leave.

In the general case this kind of processing is done with `Enumerable.Aggregate`, which could go like this:

```
Func<object, bool> aggregate = o => 
    functions.Select(f => f(o))
             .Aggregate(true, (result, @partial) => result && @partial);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jon point out, the best way is to use `Enumerable.All`. However, you can fold over a sequence using `Aggregate` so you can also do it like this:

```
Func<object, bool> folded = funcs.Aggregate((acc, f) => new Func<object, bool>(o => acc(o) && f(o)));
```

This overload requires the sequence to be non-empty but you can supply an initial value for the accumulator:

```
Func<object, bool> folded = funcs.Aggregate(new Func<object, bool>(_ => true), (acc, f) => (o => acc(o) && f(o)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
bool evaluateAllFuncs(object someObject)
{
    IEnumerable<Func<object, bool>> funcs = GetAllFuncs();
    return funcs.All(f => f(someObject)));
}
```